# Return a string from a Scala function

Tags: scala, function, if-statement

I'm brand new to Scala and I am really confused about this whole `: Unit =` business. I have a variable in my class that calls a function that returns a string. Essentially, I want the variable to call the function to find the proper value to set the variable to. I just cannot figure out how to do that with how returning things from functions work in Scala.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
val finalGrade : String = calculateFinalGrade(points)

def calculateFinalGrade(totalPoints: Int) : String = {
    if (totalPoints >= 90) { return "A" }
    else if (totalPoints < 90 && totalPoints >= 87) { return "B+" }
    else if (totalPoints < 87 && totalPoints >= 83) { return "B" }
    else if (totalPoints < 83 && totalPoints >= 80) { return "B-" }
    else if (totalPoints < 80 && totalPoints >= 77) { return "C+" }
    else if (totalPoints < 77 && totalPoints >= 73) { return "C" }
    else if (totalPoints < 73 && totalPoints >= 70) { return "C-" }
    else if (totalPoints < 70 && totalPoints >= 67) { return "D+" }
    else if (totalPoints < 67 && totalPoints >= 63) { return "D" }
    else if (totalPoints < 63 && totalPoints >= 60) { return "D-" }
    else if (totalPoints < 60) { return "F" }
}
```

When hovering over the "return"s it says "Return keyword is redundant."

Comment: A Scala function will simply return the last expression in the function. You don't need to explicitly type 'return' except in special circumstances (that should generally be avoided.)

Comment: @Metropolis true, but it still does not solve the issue

Comment: All branches of `if` statement must return a String in your case. If you omit the else branch, it is by default an Unit. Add an `else` statement in the end to add a default return value of String.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking here. What `: Unit =` business are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to type the `return` statement in scala. The reason it's complaining is that on the default case nothing is returned (there is no else statement). Try the following:

```
val finalGrade : String = calculateFinalGrade(points)

def calculateFinalGrade(totalPoints: Int) : String = 
  if (totalPoints >= 90) "A"
  else if (totalPoints >= 87) "B+"
  else if (totalPoints >= 83) "B"
  else if (totalPoints >= 80) "B-"
  else if (totalPoints >= 77) "C+"
  else if (totalPoints >= 73) "C" 
  else if (totalPoints >= 70) "C-" 
  else if (totalPoints >= 67) "D+" 
  else if (totalPoints >= 63) "D" 
  else if (totalPoints >= 60) "D-" 
  else "F"
```

Comment: The braces are unnecessary and the standard identation in Scala is of two spaces. Also, it would be good to mention that `return` is not only not needed but actually a bad practice.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah, but removing half of the `if` statements made even more readable

Comment: `List((90,"A"),(87,"B+"),(83,"B"),(80,"B-")).collectFirst { case (n,g) if ttl >= n => g }`

Comment: @som-snytt I was trying to come up with something like this, thank you!!!